# how to send a month in accordance with fullcalendar display when loaded into a url (angularJs)

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar

guys.

i have some question about fullCalendar with angularJs.

i have code for config fullcalender :

```js
.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    /* config object */
    $scope.uiConfig = {
      calendar:{
        height: 450,
        editable: true,
        header:{
          left: 'month basicWeek basicDay agendaWeek agendaDay',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'today prev,next'
        }
      }
    };
});
```

how to send a month in accordance with fullcalendar display when loaded into a url (angularJs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [viewRender](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/viewRender/) callback, in which you can access the actually displayed date range (`start` and `end`)

```
.controller('MyController', function($scope, MyService) {

    var eventSources;

    var myCallbackFn = function(view, element){
      var start = view.start;
      var end = view.end;
      // to get month only in format '01', '02' ... '12'
      var dateFormat = 'MM';
      var startMonth= start.format(dateFormat);
      // then to load events you could use something like this
      // just an example
      MyService.getEvents(startMonth).then(function(response) {
        eventSources = response;
      });
    }

    /* config object */
    $scope.uiConfig = {
      calendar:{
        height: 450,
        editable: true,
        header:{
          left: 'month basicWeek basicDay agendaWeek agendaDay',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'today prev,next'
        },
        viewRender: myCallbackFn
      }
    };
});
```